# Large game statistics database management

Tags: java, databases, statistics

I am making a management game in Java with a farming theme. I am rather beginner in software development and every steps requires lots of thoughts. I am at a point now that I want to log and keep every lots of statistics of what happens in the game. For example every time a task is completed, state of every crop field and animal  at the end of every day and so on. So I learned how to use some basic feature of Log4j2 and got a text file to log a new line every time I want to log an event. I noticed that after just 3 game days with a tiny farm size the file is already over 10kB (1KB zipped). I suspect that it will quickly become rather large for long games, bigger farm size, more complex farms... It made me wonder if it was not the best way of doing such a thing. I still have to implement a parsing method to read the text files, process the data and visualize it.

So is there a better approach? Should I write my events in a list and serialize it in binaries(I have never done that in fact I use gson for my saved games). Then again I would not want multiple hundreds of MB of data loaded up in RAM all the time. Since my project is rather small compared to many others I suspect there is a better way.

Comment: From a game play or game dev perspective, what is the intended use of these stats?

Comment: @Pikalek I intend if to be part of the game play experience, since it is a management game I want the player to be able to analyse all sorts of graphs and data. Similar to finances history graphs in simcity style games. It will also be very helpful for the dev side of things since I will be able to see what needs balancing. So basically I want to save statistics along the save game and display data in JavaFX Charts api.

Comment: Well I'd this is the way log files work. Depending on your verbosity, you write lots of stuff into them over time. You might try using a system like Linux: If the logfile is older than XX days or longer/larger than some size, Compress it into an Archive (like `log.txt.X.zip` and create a new file `log.txt`. Then after a certain number of iterations start from the beginning, overwriting the old log files.